Using a Mask to Insert Values from sklearn Iterative Imputer
I created a set of random missing values to practice with a tree imputer.  However, I'm stuck on how to overwrite the missing values into the my dataframe.  My missing values look like this:

from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer

df_post_copy = df_post.copy()
missing_mask = df_post_copy.isna()
imputer = IterativeImputer(max_iter=10, random_state=0)
imputed_values = imputer.fit_transform(df_post_copy)
df_copy[missing_mask] = imputed_values[missing_mask]

Results in:
ValueError: other must be the same shape as self when an ndarray

But the shape matches...
imputed_values.shape
(16494, 29)

The type is:
type(imputed_values)
numpy.ndarray

What I have tried since it is the right shape is to convert it to a pandas dataframe:
test_imputed_values = pd.DataFrame(imputed_values)

When I try:
df_copy[missing_mask] = test_imputed_values[missing_mask]

I get the same as above:

How do I use a mask to insert the imputed values where needed?

imputer.fit_transform(...) returns both the original values and the (previously) missing values. If you want an updated DataFrame, something like
imputed_values = imputer.fit_transform(df_post_copy)
df_post_copy.loc[:, :] = imputed_values

should work.

imputed_values = imputer.fit_transform(df_post_copy)
imputer.fit_transform returns a numpy array after filling in the missing values.
So, imputed_values has all the missing values filled in. You could convert the dataframe the usual way.
pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(df_post_copy))
will return the original dataframe with missing values filled in.
